# launch map with sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, openlayers, wms

I'm searching for a complete documentation with code how to include OpenLayers and load an own Web Map Service (WMS). I couldn't find any solution how to do it.

I already created a webapp with sencha touch. Now, I need to show a map from an WMS. Examples with google maps didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the OpenLayers documentation? That's generally the best place to look, and there are books for more detail.